# Jquery Thickbox with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, dynamic, thickbox

i will open a thickbox with content and picture without include a static page.
how i can create a dynamic conent inside the thickbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to do this. Read [**more**](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/#sectionf-1)

Comment: no, that´s fals.
i didn´t include a file with the content:# Provide a path in the href to the file/directory on the server. (href="ajaxLogin.htm") 
I will include the content by a template or by javascript.